# Android kotlin doesn't show dagger error log

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I will get straight to the problem. Android studio isn't showing me, the Dagger 2 ( version 2.14.1 )  errors in the logcat. By this I mean. In the below image you can see the error "Error:(29, 10) Unresolved reference: DaggerAppComponent". Which for me is very unclear. Is there any way to configure the project in such a way to see more information? ( I am hoping to see ( in the logcat ) something like in the second picture )

**First Image**
[image: First Image]

**Second Image**
[image]

Here is a link to the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bZ8niQK01xP-khD_20o4h7QI5XXrMYvx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In addition to @RDO's answer, make sure IntelliJ is delegating the build task to gradle, otherwise when building your project, it will only compile your Java/Kotlin files, without calling `kapt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check in gradle console in the bottom/right of the window, not in logcat